# Dividing by group

Tags: r

I have customers data and year they purchased the product.

```
df <- data.frame(CustomerID    = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
             Year = c(2012,2012,2013, 2014, 2015, 2016))
```

I want to calculate how average time that each customer bought the product. 
My desired outcome is

```
_CustomerID____|__AVG per Year____ 
  1            | 1.5
  2            | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID, Year) %>% 
  summarise(count=n()) %>% 
  summarise(AvgPerYear=mean(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some simple `dplyr` tools. Here you want to first `group_by` CustomerID, which means you are doing next steps on individual customer groups. Then, we use `summarise` to get the value you want. From your example, I am interpreting "how average time that each customer bought the product" to mean "take number of rows and divide by the number of years, inclusive of both ends".

```r
df <- data.frame(CustomerID    = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 Year = c(2012,2012,2013, 2014, 2015, 2016))
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(CustomerID) %>%
  summarise(yr_avg = n() / (max(Year) - min(Year) + 1))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   CustomerID yr_avg
#>        <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1       1.00   1.50
#> 2       2.00   1.00
```

Created on 2018-02-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

using baser:

```
aggregate(Year~CustomerID,df,function(x)length(x)/length(unique(x)))
  CustomerID Year
1          1  1.5
2          2  1.0
```